# Visualize j48 tree weka

Tags: visualization, weka, decision-tree, j48

I want to visualize my tree in a nicer layout `GraphViz`, but for some reason it doesn't show the tree at all even though it does show in the default layout.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you are on windows. Do you have the `dot` Program installed properly? `dot` or more precisely `graphwiz` is a set of unix command line tools. It might need some fiddling.

Comment: @knb I downloaded the program but I am not sure what commands I should use because I never used the command line using `weka`.